как отследить создание объекта класса python?
В библиотеке глубокого обучения pytorch есть вот такая конструкция, которая позволяет собирать нейронную сеть из разных слоев.
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x) # activation function
        x = self.conv2(x)
        return F.relu(x)

Я пишу свою библиотеку, которая внешне похожа на pytorch ( всё делается в учебных целях, заодно разбираюсь каждый раз в новых аспектах глубокого обучения.) Меня заинтересовали строки
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 20, 5)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 20, 5)

Мы создаем два объекта класса Conv2d, присваиваем ссылки на них объекту класса Model. В процессе обучения(обратного распространения ошибки), градиент последовательно с конца проходит по всем слоям такой сети (сначала по self.conv2, потом по self.conv1 ). Отсюда следует вопрос, каким образом алгоритм узнает о всех слоях объекта класса Model? Это обсуждение частично отвечает на мой вопрос. Я понял, что есть еще один класс, который собирает в некоторый список ссылки на объекты классов-"слоев" при их создании.
У себя я реализовал это так
class Parameter:
    layers = []
    calling = dict()
    number_of_classes = 0

    def __init__(self, info):
        Parameter.layers.append(info[0])
        Parameter.calling[info[0]] = info[1:]


class Conv2d:
    def __init__(self, input_channels: int, output_channels: int, kernel_size: tuple, bias = True):
        # something happen here
        Parameter([self, self.kernel_array, self.bias_array])

Такой способ работает. Однако, пока объект класса Model ровно один. Как только создается еще один объект (ещё одна нейронка), то в Parameter.layers уже хранятся ссылки для разных объектов класса Model и соответственно всё перестает работать.
Есть ли у вас идеи, как это можно избежать?

Сразу скажу что в нейронках сильно не разбираюсь, как реализовано это внутри pytorch не знаю и на задачу смотрю с точи зрения чистого python.
На ум мне пришло два варианта решения, но поведение, которое вы описали, крайне похоже на замыкания. Поэтому первым решением был такой вариант:
def ParameterObj():
    layers_list = []

    class Parameter:
        layers = layers_list
        calling = dict()
        number_of_classes = 0

        def __init__(self, info):
            Parameter.layers.append(info[0])
            Parameter.calling[info[0]] = info[1:]

    return Parameter


def Conv2dObj():
    constructor_Parameter = ParameterObj()

    class Conv2d:
        def __init__(self,
                     input_channels: int,
                     output_channels: int,
                     kernel_size: tuple,
                     bias=True
                     ):
            self.layers = constructor_Parameter([self, input_channels, output_channels])

    return Conv2d


class Model:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._constructor_Conv2d = Conv2dObj()
        self.conv1 = self._constructor_Conv2d(*args)
        self.conv2 = self._constructor_Conv2d(*[i + 1 for i in args])


m1 = Model(1, 2, 3)
print(m1.conv1.layers.layers)
# [<__main__.Conv2dObj.<locals>.Conv2d object at 0x00CB41B0>, <__main__.Conv2dObj.<locals>.Conv2d object at 0x00CB4210>]
m2 = Model(1, 2, 3)
print(m2.conv1.layers.layers)
# [<__main__.Conv2dObj.<locals>.Conv2d object at 0x00CB4330>, <__main__.Conv2dObj.<locals>.Conv2d object at 0x00CB4370>]

Как видим, расположение в памяти у объектов в разных массивах разное. В итоге, что тут происходит? При создании экземпляра класса Model, для него создаётся поле _constructor_Conv2d, в котором (логично) хранится конструктор класса Conv2d, однако с одной небольшой особенностью. При создании экземпляра с помощью этого конструктора в Parameter.layers будут попадать ссылки только на те объекты, которые создавались с помощью этого самого конструктора. В случае, если создать новый конструктор, согласно вашему вопросу, все ссылки будут попадать в другой список. Это работает благодаря тому, что мы таким же образом создаём конструктор для класса Parameter, а в классе Parameter мы замыкаем layers_list, поэтому для каждого нового ParameterObj будет создан новый пустой массив (если всё-таки непонятно, почитайте про замыкания).
Для второй идеи код будет излишен. Вот в чём суть: можно в Model создать экземпляр класса Parameter и просто передавать его при создании экземпляров Conv2d, где уже по ссылке Parameter.layers будут добавляться нужные вам данные. Ну и не забудьте инициализировать layers в init, иначе в текущем виде данный список будет общим для всех экземпляров класса.
Второй вариант, наверное, намного проще и понятнее, но если представить, что цепочка классов в будущем может стать очень большой, то первый вариант мне кажется более предпочтительным.
P.S. Вообще можно и Model обернуть в функцию что бы замкнуть constructor_Conv2d и не создавать лишнее поле в классе.

Забавно, кажется замыкать массив в ParameterObj вовсе не обязательно, а у каждого конструктора всё равно будет иметься свой отдельный layers если конструктор класса возвращается из функции. Тут уже я хотел бы услышать пояснения от кого-то

Спасибо большое @kristal за ответ. Именно с помощью замыканий я смог у себя всё реализовать.
В отдельном модуле сделал всё ту же вспомогательную сущность Parameter, но уже как замыкание
def ParameterObj():
    class Parameter:
        layers = []
        calling = dict()
        def __init__(self, info):
            Parameter.layers.append(info[0])
            Parameter.calling[info[0]] = info[1:]
    return Parameter


В основном модуле решил использовать глобальную переменную Parameter, которая будет изменяться при инициализации объекта дочернего класса (дочернего к Module), а также при вызове __call__.
Так как обучение (back propagation) происходит только после прямого прохождения по сети (forward propagation, вызова __call__), то ожидается что глобальная переменная Parameter будет ссылаться на именно тот класс Parameter, который был создан при создании нового объекта и соответственно при вызове self._constructor_Parameter = ParameterObj()
Parameter = None

class Module:
    def __init__(self):
        self._constructor_Parameter = ParameterObj()
        global Parameter
        Parameter = self._constructor_Parameter

class Conv:
    def __init__(self, input_channels: int, output_channels: int, kernel_size: tuple, bias = True):
        # something happen here
        Parameter([self, self.filter_array, np.zeros(self.n_filters)])

И теперь создание нейронной сети выглядит так
import nn

class SimpleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Сonv(3, 5)
        self.act1 = nn.Relu()
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv(5, 5)
        self.sftmx = nn.Softmax()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.act1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.sftmx(x)
        return x

model = SimpleNet()
prediction = model(x)


Ещё добавлю от себя, я видел ваше вчерашнее сообщение и таки попытался разобраться как же всё таки ваша задача реализована в PyTorch. Там очень большой объём кода, поэтому естественно я смог изучить его только поверхностно. Точно понял что ваша задача решается через __setattr__(доп обработка перед установкой значений), также насколько я понял ваш Parameter.layers не храниться в классе Parameter. Он хранится в Module и называется _parameters, причём это атрибут экземпляра, то есть они уникальный для каждого экземпляра. Но не понял на счёт Conv2d он дальний наследник Module.

Спасибо, сейчас перечитываю ваш комментарий. Теперь понял насколько можно усложнить задачу если не знать базовых вещей. Я много программирую на питоне для себя, но про setattr узнал совсем недавно. Оно как раз и являлось точным решением моего вопроса!
